# How to connect BT Fibre HomeHub to a Netgear router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

Situation is this: 
In the house I have a BT Fibre HomeHub3, connected together with a BT Openreach modem, works great in the house, no problem. 
To this HomeHub I have connected an Ethernet cable that run across the garden (through a tube) to my ManCave. In the ManCave this is presented as a wall plug-in connection point.

To this Ethernet connection point, I connected a Netgear Wireless ADSL Modem Router (DG834GT), so I now have great wifi in my ManCave and can connect all my gadgets to it.

Problem is I cannot get into the Netgear admin page to create a password! It is just open wifi connection, that anyone walking past my ManCave can connect onto!

Yes, I have tried the 192.168.0.I (which under the Netgear Modem says is the default access) and the 192.168.I.I and they don't work!

I have called Netgear and they refused to help me because it is way out of the 90 day warranty helpline period. I was asked to pay a further £40 if I wanted to speak to someone about it.

The Wifi in the ManCave is working great, but I can't just leave it open!

In my desperation, I bought another BT HomeHub3 and an Openreach box. That gave me no internet at all. 
I'd prefer to use my Netgear Wireless Router because at least it gives me my wifi I need.

I've been onto my BT admin page 192.168.I.254 and gone to Advanced Settings and gone into Home Networks, but now what?

PLEASE SOMEONE TELL ME WHAT TO DO IN BASIC TERMS! 
I have zero computer or networking knowledge and don't understand many of the terms you guys use.

What do I do?

Huge apologies if this has been covered before.... Even if it has been I wouldn't have understood!

Please someone help me!

Yours Faithfully, 
DirtyWabbit

Comment: You have written `192.168.0.I` and `192.168.I.I` - Do you mean 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to remove it from the network and connect directly to it with a spare network cable.

You should then be able to configure it via your web browser using the default router IP address (192.168.0.1). Once you have it set up how you want it, e.g Security, SSID, you can then reconnect it to your network.